# Display multiple Facebook native ads inside Android listview

Tags: android, listview, facebook-audience-network

I am working on android project where I have to implement multiple Facebook native ads inside listview. I searched over Google and Facebook Help Center but no success at all. Facebook provides sample code but they have used RecyclerView instead of ListView.